# Making jQuery top toolbar less jumpy

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, toolbar

I am trying to affix a toolbar to the top of the page.  The only thing that can push it out of the way is the logo.  My affect works but the scrolling is very jumpy.  If one scrolls very fast, especially on a mobile phone it takes a few ms to reposition itself and the effect is noticeable.  This is simply an example.  In my real site there is a logo image and the toolbar contains images.  The text should flow under the toolbar hence the high z-index.  The logo should push it down if the user scrolls to the top.

```
        <html>
                <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                #logo {
                        width:100%;
                        height:34px;
                }

                #toolbar {
                        position: fixed;
                        top: 35px;
                        z-index:1000;
                }
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                        <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
                        <div id="toolbar">TOOLBAR</div>
                        <div id="content">
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                                <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
                        </div>
                </body>
                <script>
                  $(document).scroll(function(e) {
                    if($(window).scrollTop() < 35)
                        $("#toolbar").css('top',(35 - $(window).scrollTop()) +  'px');
                      else
                   $("#toolbar").css('top','0px');
               });
               </script>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking for something a little more smoother.   I would recommend using Ben Alman's throttle and debounce jquery plugin.  **It will reduce the number of callback events for better performance, especially with mobile devices.**

Also you can include some animation if you want the sliding effect to be smoother and slower.

Here is a demo that you can play with that includes both (you need the throttle/debounce and jqueryui plugins:

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/collabcoders/vHs4s/**

```
    $(document).scroll( $.throttle( 250, scrolling ) ); 

    function scrolling() {
         if($(window).scrollTop() < 35)
               $("#toolbar").animate({
                    top: 35 - $(window).scrollTop()
               }, 250);  
         else                 
               $("#toolbar").animate({
                    top: "0"
               }, 250);
        }​
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with our `#toolbar` div absolutely positioned, then switch to 'fixed' positioning when scrollTop() breaches 35 pixels. This avoids having to animate anything, which sounds like where your are running into trouble.

See this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2LLry/

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #header {
                position:fixed;
                top:0px;
                z-index: 1000;
            }
            #logo {
                    width:100%;
                    height:34px;
                    display: block;
            }

            #toolbar {
                    top: 35px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

        <script>
          $(document).scroll(function(e) {
            if($(window).scrollTop() == 0)
                 $("#logo").show();
            else
                     $("#logo").hide();
          });
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
        <div id="toolbar">TOOLBAR</div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" style="padding-top:50px;">
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsum doler</p><br />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```